# Repeating this process 3 times

Tags: python, loops, random, grouping, repeat

How Can I get this long code process to create 3 trials rather than one on a single run?

```
import numpy
import math
import random
members=4
n_groups =4
participants=list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups
#print participants 
random.shuffle(participants)

with open('myfile1.txt','w') as tf:
    for i in range(n_groups):
        group = participants[i*members:(i+1)*members]
        for participant in group:
            tf.write(str(participant)+' ')
        tf.write('\n')

with open('myfile1.txt','r') as tf:
    g = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in tf.readlines()]
    print(g)


my_groups =g

def get_rating(group):
    return len(set(group))



for each_grp in my_groups:  
    print(get_rating(each_grp))
```

Usually the outcome would be:

```
[[2, 4, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2, 1], [3, 3, 4, 4], [2, 4, 1, 2]]
4
3
2
3
```

How could i get this to repeat the whole process n number of times so it gives something like (e.g. repeat 3 times):

```
[[3, 1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 1, 1], [2, 3, 1, 4], [4, 4, 3, 2]]
3 
3
4
3
[[3, 1, 4, 1], [4, 3, 3, 4], [2, 2, 2, 2], [4, 1, 1, 3]]
3
2
1
3
[[3, 1, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 2], [1, 1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 1, 2]]
2
2
3
3
```

I could just copy the code 3 times but I was wondering if there was another way?

Comment: put the code you want to repeat in a for loop https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: I want to repeat the whole thing, not sure where to put it in or how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a loop and put everything in it :

```
import numpy
import math
import random
for i in range(3):
  # everything is in, see the indentation
  members=4
  n_groups =4
  participants=list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups
  #print participants 
  random.shuffle(participants)

  with open('myfile1.txt','w') as tf:
      for i in range(n_groups):
          group = participants[i*members:(i+1)*members]
          for participant in group:
              tf.write(str(participant)+' ')
          tf.write('\n')

  with open('myfile1.txt','r') as tf:
      g = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in tf.readlines()]
      print(g)


  my_groups =g

  def get_rating(group):
      return len(set(group))

  for each_grp in my_groups:  
      print(get_rating(each_grp))
```

Which outputs :

```
[[3, 4, 2, 1], [3, 2, 2, 1], [1, 3, 4, 4], [3, 2, 1, 4]]
4
3
3
4
[[3, 2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 3, 1], [4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 4, 1, 2]]
3
3
2
3
[[3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2], [2, 1, 2, 1], [3, 4, 4, 1]]
2
3
2
3
```